# Conditional CSS if div content wraps

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar across the top of the page. It's just made up of a `div` wrapping stylized `a` links. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LenMU/)

```
<div class="navigation">
    <a href="someplace">1</a>   
    <a href="someplace">2</a>
    <a href="someplace">3</a>
    <a href="someplace">4</a>   
</div>
```

When the user shrinks the page and the links go beyond the width of the window, some of them drop below. What I'd like is for a border to go at the bottom of everything but the last child--that is, the last children that just became the last children because of window resize and not actual code placement. Is this possible?

Comment: please add your actual code in rather than only provide a jsFiddle. there is a reason you were forced to put a code block into your question.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I wasn't forced to this time but sure.

Comment: you weren't forced to "this time" because you put `div` and `a` as code blocks. its the cheaters way to get around the requirement, and highly frowned upon. greatly appreciate you making the change.

Comment: Could you set a height on your div and then put a border on that?

Comment: @Chad I could, but if the window is resized to extreme tininess, the border would only appear to be around the topmost link group.

Comment: I think I'm having trouble visualizing what you're asking for. If you put together some simple diagrams, I should be able to help you.

Comment: @Chad Hope this is explanatory enough: http://jsfiddle.net/LenMU/9/ Pretending that the navigation widths are what the user would've resized their window to. I basically just want a separator between 'rows'.

Comment: This is the only way with CSS I can think to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/LenMU/13/

Comment: @Chad Looks simple and perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
@media (max-width: 100px) {
    .navigation a { border-bottom: 1px solid red; }
    .navigation a:last-child { border-bottom: none; } 
}
}
```

Comment: Nice, but is there any way to make this work for other formations (eg. one below or two below instead of just one column) without calculating the max-width of everything? The link text I am using for real aren't of all the same length, and said length will change depending on the language.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called Responsive design. You may want to look into a framework or some tutorials on responsive layouts. 

http://www.getskeleton.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want a separation between rows you can use this code that evaluates if some `a` element are separated from the top:

```
$('.navigation a').each (function () {
        var off=$(this).offset().top;
        if (off > 10) {
            $('.navigation a').css('border-bottom','3px solid red');
        } else {
            $('.navigation a').css('border-bottom','none');
        }
    });
```

Check it here working **http://jsfiddle.net/LenMU/16/**